# Order by a date of the first hasMany child of a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have the following Structure for events and there recurrences

Event: (id, name, venue)
has_many :occurences

Occurence(id, date, event_id)
belongs_to :event

I want to get events (only event data) that have a recurrence greater than today
(occurences.date>Date.Today)

Events should be ordered by the date of their next recurrence(greater than today) in chronological order

The following query gives me event data alright but it doesn't let me order

```
Event.joins(:occurences).where("occurences.date>?",DateTime.now).distinct#.order('occurences.date')
```

but I can't order it since it says

> Expression #1 of ORDER BY clause is not in SELECT list, references
>   column 'eventdatabase.occurences.starts'

I need to use distinct to ensure I get only one event regardless of how many occurences it has

I am using mysql and rails5

Comment: can you try this solution https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/issues/5622

Answer (score 0):

I'm interpreting

> Events should be ordered by the date of their next recurrence(greater than today) in chronological order

as earliest `occurance.date`.

```
Event.joins(:occurences)
     .where("occurences.date>?",DateTime.now)
     .group(:id)
     .select('events.*, min(occurences.date) as next_recurrence')
     .order('next_recurrence')
```

A group by is like a more powerful distinct.  You will get one row (for one "group").  Technically we should group by `events.*`, but mysql will cheat and let us group by a primary key to do the same thing.

When doing a group by, the aggregate functions, such as `min` work on the group.

Comment: Damn! 5 mins faster than me :)

Answer (score 0):

For this task the SQL query may look like:

```
SELECT E.id AS event_id, MIN(OC.date) AS next_date
FROM events E
  JOIN occurences OC ON OC.event_id = E.id
WHERE OC.date > NOW()
GROUP BY E.id
ORDER BY MIN(OC.date);
```

Here is sandbox: http://rextester.com/HCTE57488

So I guess the Ruby code will be:

```
Event.joins(:occurences)
     .where('occurences.date > ?', DateTime.now)
     .group('events.id')
     .order('min(occurences.date)')
```